# Как пройтись по массиву в php

Tags: php

Суть задания такая. В форме мы передаем в метод POST название домена. Так же у нас имеется база данных с черным списком доменов. И мы должны проверить, будет ли $_POST['domain_name'] == row['name'], структура массива $ row у нас примерно такая:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => testblacklist.com ) Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => qwerty.ru ) Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => mainmain.ru )
```

Вот пытался реализовать вот так, но не вышло:

```
function black_list($domain_name)
{
    $black_l = array();
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'wordpress');
    $query = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM black_list');
   
    if($query->num_rows) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $query->num_rows; ++$i) {
            $row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if($row['name'] == _POST['domain_name'])
                return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Эта функция вызывает в другой функции, где мы передаем $domain_name

Comment: зачем плодить много одинаковых вопросов?

Comment: ну НЕ ВЫБИРАЮТ из базы все значения сразу!! Сделай выборку по WHERE domain_column = $domain_name

Comment: Потому что везде отвечают по разному

Answer (score 1):

Правильно @Jean-Claude  подсказывает.

Вся работа сводится **с одним именем домена** к запросу вида:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as cnt FROM black_list WHERE name = 'УКАЗАННЫЙ ДОМЕН';
```

И потом посмотреть значение `cnt` и вернуть результат. Типа `return $cnt > 0`

---

При сравнении всех доменов сразу вся работа сводится к этому:

- Берём весь список доменов из запроса

  ```
  $domainNames = array_column($arrayFromRequest, 'domain_name');
  ```
- Делаем запрос вида

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(1) as cnt FROM black_list WHERE name IN ('СПИСОК', 'ИМЁН', 'ЧЕРЕЗ', 'ЗАПЯТУЮ');
  ```
- Смотрим значение `cnt` и возвращаем результат. Типа `return $cnt > 0`